# How to format the HTML output of CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I want to format the html output of CKEDITOR. I am using this code to set the rules for `p` tags

```
editor_new = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'editorSpace',{
                on:{
                    instanceReady: function(ev){
                        this.dataProcessor.writer.lineBreakChars = '';
                        this.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p', {
                            indent: false,
                            breakBeforeOpen: false,
                            breakAfterOpen: false,
                            breakBeforeClose: false,
                            breakAfterClose: false
        });
```

It has changed the output format from

```
<p>Tony</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Stark</p>
```

to

```
<p>Tony</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p> 
<p>Stark</p>
```

But the problem with this is when I use `editor.getData()` on the editor, it adds one `\n` after every line as it is a normal string. I want to eliminate that `\n` on the backend side.

I want to configure the html of editor as this

```
<p>Tony</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Stark</p>
```

without any spaces and breaks so that the backend does not need to care about the data coming from frontend and stores it in database as-is. Is there any way I can achieve this?

PS: I have just shown example for `p` tags. I want to achieve this for every tag. In short, I want to generate html in the same way a minified js file stores javascript content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get rid of [HTML Output Writer](http://ckeditor.com/addon/htmlwriter) plugin, i.e. with [`config.removePlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removePlugins):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    removePlugins: 'htmlwriter'
} );
```

Comment: I removed the 'htmlwriter' plugin but there is no effect on the html output. It is now producing the same old output with extra spaces.

Comment: @akg Are you sure you removed it? See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/99280unp/).

Comment: -yupp it is working on the js fiddle. I have used this code - editor_new = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'editorSpace',{
                    removePlugins: 'htmlwriter'
                });     where 'editorSpace' is the id of the div. I dont know what is the problem from my side.